# How can I fix this error on numpy linalg.py?

Tags: python

I get this error on IntelliJ IDE. What's the problem?
Its a code for Gauss-Seidel Approximation Method.
I have 18 equations to solve, and the code is based on the description on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method) about this method:
Ax =b
the matrix A is decomposed into a lower triangular component L and a strictly upper triangular component U.

Error:

```
File "D:/pyhton projects/guase/guase.py", line 53, in <module>
    Gauss_Seidel(A, b, error_s)
  File "D:/pyhton projects/guase/guase.py", line 15, in Gauss_Seidel
    xn = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(L), (b - np.dot(U, x)))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in inv
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 551, in inv
    ainv = _umath_linalg.inv(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 97, in _raise_linalgerror_singular
    raise LinAlgError("Singular matrix")
numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

My code:

```
    import numpy as np
def Gauss_Seidel(A, b, error_s):
    [m, n] = np.shape(A)

    U = np.triu(A, 1)
    L = np.tril(A)

    x = np.ones((m, 1))
    err = np.ones((m, 1)) * 100

    while np.max(err) > error_s:
        xn = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(L), (b - np.dot(U, x)))
        err = abs((xn - x) / xn) * 100
        x = xn

    for i in range(0, m):
        print('x[%0.0f] = %6.4f --- Error: %0.4f %%' % (i + 1, x[i], err[i]))


    # T1 T2 T3 T4 T5 T6 T7 T8 T9 T10 T11 T12 T13 T14 T15 T16 T17 T18


A = np.array(np.mat('-4,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;\
                     1,0,0,-4,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;\
                     0,0,0,1,0,0,-4,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;\
                     0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,-4,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0;\
                     0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,-4,1,0,1,0,0;\
                     0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,-3,1,0;\
                     1,-4,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;\
                     0,1,0,1,-4,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;\
                     0,0,0,0,1,0,1,-4,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;\
                     0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,-4,1,0,1,0,0,0,0;\
                     0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,-4,1,0,1,0;\
                     0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,-3,1;\
                     0,1,-4,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;\
                     0,0,1,0,1,-4,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;\
                     0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,-4,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0;\
                     0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,-4,0,0,1,0,0,0;\
                     0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,-4,0,0,1;\
                     0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,-3'))

b = np.array(np.mat('0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;-141.42;-200;-141.42;0;141.42;200'))

error_s = 5

Gauss_Seidel(A, b, error_s)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you print out the determinant of L, you get 0. This is the definition of a Singular matrix, for which an inverse does not exist.
The problem is in that line:

```py
xn = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(L), (b - np.dot(U, x)))
```